# Generate Quickbooks Web Connect Service

Tags: grails

Does anyone have code for a Web Service with works with the Quickbooks Web Connector in Grails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails runs on the JVM and can easily call java code such as that generated when using Apache Access to call web services. For more info on the QuickBooks web service and how to call it from Java see
http://developer.intuit.com/support/technical/?id=392
The info in this article should work with grails assuming you get the Apache Access library. You can also look at using [Groovy WS](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS) to call any WSDL based web service. I've tried it but had issues with complex types; maybe you'll have better luck.

Comment: I generated the code using Apache AXIS and then cut and paste the code.